# Finding downward force of lever bar

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, applied-mechanics, statics, dynamics

I am working on a DIY project, I am trying to replicate a bar compressor which for some reason is only sold in Europe so I thought it would be fun to make my own without having to waste so much material. I simply want to make sure the force going down with the plate somewhat replaces a person to jump in the trashcan. Somewhere above 80+ lbs, since I am no engineer I was wondering how would one go about finding the force applied going down to the trash if about 50lbs is pulling down the lever. I understand that materials are key to this but as an amateur I just wanted to know how to get started. Sorry for posting here but I thought it would suit this page the most for this question. Thank you.

[image: Drawing of beam]

[image: Actual use of bar]

Comment: The force multipler is about  (20.5+18.5)/18.5 which is roughly double the input. Altough the real value is slightly less than this and varies by angle. This is just statics.

Comment: How is this not just a *very basic* statics problem from high school?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input force is 18.5+20.5 ft away from the fulcrum and the load is 18.5 away from the fulcrum.

This means the force applied to the load is $\frac{(18.5+20.5)}{18.5} = 2.1$ times greater than the input force or for an input force of 50 lbs you get an output force of **105 lbs**.

However this assumes that all forces are applied *perpendicular* to the line between point and fulcrum. If this is not the case then you need to decompose the forces into tangential and normal components.

Comment: Its about 0-15% less because of the angle across the work cycle assuming force is down, this is why i said its about double. I would have expected a graph from you :P  but yes comparable to jumping on top. Less messy perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Balance the moments acting.

So,

EffortForce x 39 x cos 30 = 18.5 cos 30 x resulting force.

Or more accurately,

[image]

Sin(90+ theta - alpha ) x 39 x effortForce = cos(theta) x 18.5 x requiredForce

This equation will give you answer for any angle of level.

Answer (score -3):

The force at the middle would be like 2 times bigger than the input. I calculated for this exact situation and it would be around 94lbs.

Comment: How did you arrive at this answer? Without showing your working this is a very low quality answer. A large part of this site is the *how* and the *why*, not just the final number.